# Store NSString to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, string, cocoa-touch

I think I quite got it. Maybe someone can tell me what is wrong.

`NSString:`

```
Patrick\nNice picture!\nAndy\nI like it\nTim\nMe too\n
```

I want to store this string into an `NSArray` like:

```
- NSArray
    - NSDictionary
           - name (e.g. Andy)
           - kommentar (e.g. I like it)
```

It's somehow a logical error, but it drives me nuts ... (Code is working but not doing the right thing.)

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ([[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count] - 1 / 2); i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary * comment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        [comment setValue:[[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"name"];
        [comment setValue:[[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"kommentar"];
    }
    [commentsArray addObject:comment];
    //NSLog(@"%@", [comment description]);
    //NSLog(@"Bla.");
    //comment = nil;
}

for (int a = 0; a <= [commentsArray count] - 1; a++) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ Nachricht: %@", [[commentsArray objectAtIndex:a] valueForKey:@"name"], [[commentsArray objectAtIndex:a] valueForKey:@"kommentar"]);
}
```

I get:

```
Name: Patrick Nachricht: Patrick
Name: (null) Nachricht: (null)
Name: Andy Nachricht: Andy
Name: (null) Nachricht: (null)
Name: Tim Nachricht: Tim
Name: (null) Nachricht: (null)
Name:  Nachricht: //that's because of the last \n
Name: (null) Nachricht: (null)
```

I also tried

```
[comment setValue:[[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:i + 1] forKey:@"kommentar"];
```

... but that gives me the `out of bounds` - error, which is clear.

**SOLUTION:**

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= ([[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count] - 1); i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary * comment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        [comment setValue:[[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:i - 1] forKey:@"name"];
        [comment setValue:[[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"kommentar"];
    }
    [commentsArray addObject:comment];
}

for (int a = 0; a <= [commentsArray count] - 1; a++) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ Nachricht: %@", [[commentsArray objectAtIndex:a] valueForKey:@"name"], [[commentsArray objectAtIndex:a] valueForKey:@"kommentar"]);
}
```

Comment: Typically, in a situation like this where your code is working but not doing the right thing, I find that the solution is to make it work **and** do the right thing too.

Comment: All I wanted to mention is that there is no syntax error so that people focus on the logical aspects.

Comment: Okay, so do you maybe think it might have been smart for you to mention something about what your code was actually doing instead of the right thing??

Comment: See my edited answer. `yuji`: Misread your comment, I apologize.

Comment: OK, I got it. Will answer the question by myself as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ([[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] count] - 1); i++) {
NSMutableDictionary * comment = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if (i % 2 != 0) {
    [comment setValue:[[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:i - 1] forKey:@"name"];
    [comment setValue:[[aStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"kommentar"];
}
[commentsArray addObject:comment];
}

for (int a = 0; a <= [commentsArray count] - 1; a++) {
NSLog(@"Name: %@ Nachricht: %@", [[commentsArray objectAtIndex:a] valueForKey:@"name"], [[commentsArray objectAtIndex:a] valueForKey:@"kommentar"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to explain better, but taking a quick look at your code I would question.

1). Why are you only looping through half the array? (count - 1)/2
in the example you give you will only be reading the first two items.  edit - actually with your syntax it will 1 / 2 then - 1... so...

2). Why are you instantiating your comment object and adding it to your array even if your requirement of i%2 = 0 is not met.

It would seem to me (at a quick glance) the above with your example will result in an array where every seconf object in the array  is empty.  Put your add in the if statement.